# Elasticsearch: nested object under path [messages] is not of nested type

Tags: elasticsearch, search-engine

I am having a lot of issues with the nested type mapping in Elasticsearch, I have ran this to create my index:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/thread_and_messages' -d 
'{"mappings" : {
    "message": {
        "properties": {
            "messages": {
                "type": "nested", 
                "include_in_parent": true, 
                "properties": {
                    "message_id": {"type": "string"}, 
                    "message_text": {"type": "string"}, 
                    "message_nick": {"type": "string"}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}}'
```

Then this is how I've indexed a document:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/thread_and_messages/thread/1' -d 
'{
    "thread_id":"2", 
    "thread_name":"Windows", 
    "created":"Wed Mar 25 2015", 
    "first_nick":"Admin", 
    "messages":[
        {"message_id":"5", "message_text":" Pc with a mouse", "message_nick":"Admin"},
        {"message_id":"6", "message_text":"Keyboard", "message_nick":"Admin"},
        {"message_id":"7", "message_text":"iPhone", "message_nick":"Admin"},
        {"message_id":"8", "message_text":"Gym", "message_nick":"Admin"}]"
}'
```

This is my query:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/thread_and_messages/thread/_search' -d 
'{"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {"match": {"thread_name": "windows"}}, 
            {"nested": {
                "path": "messages", "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "match": {"messages.message_text": "gym"}
                    }]
                }
                }
            }}
        ]}
    }
}'
```

I am receiving this error, even though I have clearly mapped messages as a nested type:

```
QueryParsingException[[thread_and_messages] [nested] nested object under path [messages] is not of nested type
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you defined your mapping for the type `"message"`, but then indexed your document as the type `"thread"`. So the `"thread"` type is dynamically created, but not with a nested sub-type. I ran your code as posted, then looked at the mapping:

```
GET /test_index/_mapping
...
{
   "test_index": {
      "mappings": {
         "message": {
            "properties": {
               "messages": {
                  "type": "nested",
                  "include_in_parent": true,
                  "properties": {
                     "message_id": {
                        "type": "string"
                     },
                     "message_nick": {
                        "type": "string"
                     },
                     "message_text": {
                        "type": "string"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         },
         "thread": {
            "properties": {
               "created": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "first_nick": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "messages": {
                  "properties": {
                     "message_id": {
                        "type": "string"
                     },
                     "message_nick": {
                        "type": "string"
                     },
                     "message_text": {
                        "type": "string"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "thread_id": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "thread_name": {
                  "type": "string"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

When I changed `"message"` to `"thread"` in the mapping and started over, your query worked fine.

Here is the code I used to test it:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/8a06b7849cf49006afd464ed4ee5b4e770759d5a

Comment: The sense.qbox.io link is dead